# Why choose second column when making roc curve???? y_prob = y_prob.iloc[:,1]

Tags: python

I saw many tutorials and machine learning projects where every person chose the second column  of the `y_prob`.
I want to ask what's the reason to choose the second column? Can we select the 1st column or make a roc curve on every column?

```
y_prob = LR.predict_proba(x_test_bc)
y_prob = pd.DataFrame(y_prob)
y_prob = y_prob.iloc[:,1] # this is the line in question
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba):

> Returns probability estimates for all classes are ordered by the label of classes.

Most of the Logistic Regression examples use 2-label target variable and labels  mostly are `0` and `1`. If this is the case, then `predict_proba()` returns an array of probabilities for **label 0** and **label 1**, respectively. The order of labels is *assumed* by many as `[label_0, label_1]` (because of the natural order of `0` followed by `1`) and if the attention if required by **positive** samples then **second element i.e. index 1 of array** from `predict_proba()` is analysed (which happens to be probability for **label 1**).

However, this is is not the safe way, if the *assumed* label order is not honoured by the classifier.

### Correct way

`classes_` attribute of LR classifier returns the order of the labels. Use this attribute to find correct index of the label and use this index in the probability array.

For example:

```py
lr_classifier = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

# Lets say positive sample is labelled as 1
label_1 = 1

# Find the index of positive label i.e. label = 1
idx_label_1 = list(lr_classifier.classes_).index(label_1)

# This above index in predict_proba()
lr_classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:, idx_label_1]
```